# A question about a primitive root mod $p=2^{2^k}+1$, where $p$ is prime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, primitive-roots, legendre-symbol

Let $p=2^{2^k}+1$ be a prime where $k\ge1$. Prove that the set of quadratic non-residues mod $p$ is the same as the set of primitive roots mod $p$. Use this to show that $7$ is a primitive root mod $p$.

I've already shown the theorem to be true. The second part asks to use the first part to show the result which leads me to think that I have to show $7$ is a quadratic non-residue mod $p$ then use the first part to imply that it must be a primitive root.

To show $7$ to be a quadratic non-residue for $k\ge1$ is to show that the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{7}{p}\right) = -1$. Now, $$\left(\frac{7}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{p}{7}\right)(-1)^{\left(\frac{7-1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)} = \left(\frac{p}{7}\right)(-1)^{3(2^{(2^k)-1})} = \left(\frac{p}{7}\right)$$
since $2^{2^k-1}$ is even (as $k\ge1$).

Then it suffices to know $p$ mod $7$ to determine the Legendre symbol. Since $\left(\frac{p}{7}\right) = -1$ when $p\equiv 3,5,6$ mod $7$, I suspect I somehow have to show that $p$ must be congruent to those values but I don't know how to do that. Although, trivially, $p\not\equiv 1$ mod $7$ otherwise, $7|2^{2^k}$ which is not possible.

Unfortunately, I don't know where to go from here.

Any guidance would be appreciated. However, assuming I’ve taken the right approach, I would prefer a constructive hint to a full blown solution, as I think I may be able to work it out on my own, given a nudge in the right direction.

Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: I am struggling with a VERY similar problem *cough* (and currently on mobile), but will try to assist. Notice, possibly from previous problems, we would really love to work mod 28, as that is what (7/p) 'uses'. What is p mod 7? What is p mod 4? So then what is p mod 28?

Comment: I think your proof doesn't need to consider $k = 1$ as a special case since $2^{2^1-1} = 2$ is also even :)

Comment: As for the question of computing the Legendre symbol, you can try to compute a few values of the sequence $2^{2^k} +1 \pmod 7$. Do you notice any patterns? You can also use some knowledge about the behavior of the sequence $2^x \pmod n$ for $x = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$

Comment: @TobErnack Of course. You are right. Edited!

Comment: @TobErnack I noticed this earlier, but didn't really know how to approach it rigorously. I will give it another try.

Answer (score 2):

Powers of 2 are congruent to $1, 2, $ or $4$ modulo $7$ according as the power is congruent to $0, 1$ or $2$ modulo $3$ (as $3$ is the order of $2$ modulo $7$). As $3\nmid 2^k,$ $p\equiv 3\ or\ 5 \pmod 7.$